# Git with smart HTTP and suexec: repository not found

Tags: git, suexec, smart-http

I'm trying to install my own Git repository on one of my servers with smart HTTP.

It works on a virtual server without suexec, but doesn't on my production server that has suexec enabled. When I try to clone or push it says:

> fatal: repository 'http://domain.tld/git/project/' not found

Apache configuration is like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Options -Indexes +ExecCGI

    ServerAdmin user@domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld

    ServerName domain.tld

    Alias /fcgi-bin/ /var/www/domain.tld/fcgi-bin/
    SuexecUserGroup domainuser domainuser

    ########## GIT ##########

    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git/git_domain
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
    ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/git/git_domain/git-http-backend/

    Alias /git /var/www/git/git_domain
    <Directory /usr/lib/git-core>
        Options +ExecCGI +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/git/git_domain>
        Options -Indexes -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ########## PROJECT DIRS HTPASS ##########

        <LocationMatch "^/git/project1/.*$">
#            DAV on
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "project1"
            AuthUserFile /var/www/git/gitpass/domain/project1
            Require valid-user
        </LocationMatch>

    ########## /PROJECT DIRS HTPASS ##########
    ########## /GIT ##########
```

If I disable

> ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/git/git_domain/git-http-backend/

I can clone, but push, because it works with DAV in that case.

I think I changed all the files' owners and permissions to the right value (domainuser, 755) and suexec doesn't complain about anything in its log.

Can anyone tell me where I did something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy: `mod_suexec` wipes all the environment variables before running the target program and so all your `SetEnv` directives have no effect.

Unfortunately, the last time I checked (facing the same problem) `mod_suexec` had no "whitelist" configuration knob for the environment variables and so the correct approach is this:

1. Create a script wrappnig your actual `git-http-backend`.

   Seems like you have one already.
2. Reformulate all the relevant `SetEnv` directives there using the shell's `export` builtin.

   That is,

   ```
   SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git/git_domain
   ```

   becames

   ```
   export GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/git/git_domain
   ```

   in the script code.

If you need the same virtualhost config file to work both in "normal" mode and under `mod_suexec` put extensive comment about this quirk next to the block of your `SetEnv` directives suggesting the next guy to keep them in sync with whatever is placed in the wrapper script.

More details on `mod_suexec` behaviour can be found [here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Suexec).

Comment: It worked!
The wrapper script I had contained this:
`!/bin/bash
PATH_INFO=$SCRIPT_URL
GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/git/git_domain
REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
export GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL=true
usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend`

Because a tutorial sad it should have looked like this. After removing all the lines but
`!/bin/bash
export GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/git/git_domain
usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend`

and "exported" GIT_PROJECT_ROOT it works as expected.

Thank you kostix!

Comment: @vdavid, the `REMOTE_USER` and `GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL` variables might be useful if you understand what they do. The former is exported by the web server to a CGI program iff the web server had performed client authenticaition, and in this case the variable contains the authenticated user name. The latter tells Git that it should consider all repositories as "exported", and not only those which contain the `git-daemon-export-ok` file in them.

Comment: @vdavid, the `REMOTE_USER` variable might be useful if you want to use HTTP along with the `gitolite` Git hosting front-end for in this case `gitolite` does not perform its own SSH pubkey-based authentication -- relegating this to the web server -- and hence wants to know the name of the authenticated user to apply its access control rules.